# Find the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ 1}{n^{2}(2n-1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum $ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}(2n-1)}$

$= 1 + \dfrac{1}{3\cdot 2^{2}} + \dfrac{1}{5\cdot 3^{2}} + \dfrac{1}{7\cdot 4^{2}} \ldots$

Then, I'm stuck.
I didn't find any pattern to solve. 
I just need a hint.

Comment: @John, are $3$ separate edits necessary?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @Ak19 I usually do the title and the body of text separately to max out on points. It's not illegal, just maybe frowned upon!

Comment: Its largely irrelevant.  After you pass a certain reputation, edits no longer award points anyways.  That being said, it is certainly cleaner to have all edits happen at once if possible, but so long as an edit actively helps it should be accepted.

Comment: Your sum has the value $$\frac{1}{6} \left(6 \log (16)-\pi ^2\right)$$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition),
$$\frac{1}{n^2(2n-1)}=4\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)-\frac{1}{n^2}.$$
Hence
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ 1}{n^{2}(2n-1)}=
4\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}
-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ 1}{n^{2}}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm getting $4 \log 2 - \pi ^{2} /6$

Comment: @Mathsaddict Correct!

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2(2n-1)}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2}{n}\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{4}{2n-1}-\frac{4}{2n}-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=4\ln2-\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$