# Evaluate the sum of series convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Compute     $\sum\frac{1}{n^2(2n-1)}$ assuming that $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ = $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

If we multiply and divide the fraction by 2n+1 we get $\sum\frac{2n+1}{n^2(4n^2-1)}$

but still I couldn't proceed.  How to use $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ = $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$
to evaluate the series sum?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3328952/find-the-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1n22n-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\frac1{n^2(2n-1)}=\frac{4}{2 n-1}-\frac4{2n}-\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\sum\dfrac{1}{n^{2}(2n-1)}&=-\sum\dfrac{2n-1-2n}{n^{2}(2n-1)}\\
&=-\sum\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}+2\dfrac{1}{n(2n-1)}\\
&=-\sum\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}+4\sum\left(\dfrac{1}{2n-1}-\dfrac{1}{2n}\right)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- add $\sum \frac 1{n^2}$
- convert what remains into $\frac 1{2n}-\frac 1{2n-1}$
- use $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}n=-\ln(2)$